# iOS/Swift: how to detect touch action on a UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, touch-up-inside

I would like to detect the touch action on a UITextField.

It seems the "Touch Up Inside" action is not fired by touching inside the textfield.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

It seems "Touch Up Inside" is not enabled for `UITextField`, but "Touch Down" works.

So the solution is as follows:

**Swift 4.x**

```
myTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myTargetFunction), for: .touchDown)
@objc func myTargetFunction(textField: UITextField) {
    print("myTargetFunction")
}
```

**Swift 3.x**

```
myTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myTargetFunction), for: UIControlEvents.touchDown)

@objc func myTargetFunction(textField: UITextField) {
    print("myTargetFunction")
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but doesn't work as of Swift 4.

Comment: Works for me, 4.1 swift

Comment: i am trying to call webservice on textfield click on keyboard comes and webservice never called. But when i use editingBegin property that time web service called and it goes in infinity loop.
Can anyone tell me how can make textfield uneditable,

Comment: shouldBeginEditing is th best delegate method for this purpose.

Comment: It working provided text field are not in scrollview

Answer (score 40):

## Swift 4 and higher:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == myTextField {
            print("You edit myTextField")
        }
    }
}
```

This is a delegate function.

Comment: @Gowthaman you might have forgotten to set the textfield delegate to self (the ViewController)

Answer (score 13):

here's Swfit:

and you don't need to use the "touchUpInside" just use the delegate methods like so:

Make your View controller a delegate:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == myTextField {
        return true // myTextField was touched
    }
}
```

Here's the other delegate methods:

```
protocol UITextFieldDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {

    optional func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool // return NO to disallow editing.
    optional func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) // became first responder
    optional func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool // return YES to allow editing to stop and to resign first responder status. NO to disallow the editing session to end
    optional func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) // may be called if forced even if shouldEndEditing returns NO (e.g. view removed from window) or endEditing:YES called

    optional func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool // return NO to not change text

    optional func textFieldShouldClear(textField: UITextField) -> Bool // called when clear button pressed. return NO to ignore (no notifications)
    optional func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool // called when 'return' key pressed. return NO to ignore.
}
```

from swift docs:

```
struct UIControlEvents : RawOptionSetType {
    init(_ rawValue: UInt)
    init(rawValue: UInt)

    static var TouchDown: UIControlEvents { get } // on all touch downs
    static var TouchDownRepeat: UIControlEvents { get } // on multiple touchdowns (tap count > 1)
    static var TouchDragInside: UIControlEvents { get }
    static var TouchDragOutside: UIControlEvents { get }
    static var TouchDragEnter: UIControlEvents { get }
    static var TouchDragExit: UIControlEvents { get }
    static var TouchUpInside: UIControlEvents { get }
    static var TouchUpOutside: UIControlEvents { get }
    static var TouchCancel: UIControlEvents { get }

    static var ValueChanged: UIControlEvents { get } // sliders, etc.

    static var EditingDidBegin: UIControlEvents { get } // UITextField
    static var EditingChanged: UIControlEvents { get }
    static var EditingDidEnd: UIControlEvents { get }
    static var EditingDidEndOnExit: UIControlEvents { get } // 'return key' ending editing

    static var AllTouchEvents: UIControlEvents { get } // for touch events
    static var AllEditingEvents: UIControlEvents { get } // for UITextField
    static var ApplicationReserved: UIControlEvents { get } // range available for application use
    static var SystemReserved: UIControlEvents { get } // range reserved for internal framework use
    static var AllEvents: UIControlEvents { get }
}
```

UITextField doesn't respond to "touchUpInside" see to the right side, you'll find it's acceptable control events

Comment: Thanks @Lacerax,  but I would like to detect then the user taps the textfield. I am already detecting editing with this function `myTextField.addTarget(self, action: "myTargetFunction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)`, without the need of a UITextFieldDelegate

Comment: so you mean touch but not enter the textfield, right?

Comment: You shoudl read the docs on UITextField, it only responds to these selector methods:   UIControlEventEditingDidBegin     = 1 << 16,     // UITextField
    UIControlEventEditingChanged      = 1 << 17,
    UIControlEventEditingDidEnd       = 1 << 18,
    UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit = 1 << 19,     // 'return key' ending editing

Comment: touchupinside is NOT one of those

Comment: look at the answer in one se

Comment: Thanks Larcerax! It seems TouchDown works though!
It works in this way:
`myTextField.addTarget(self, action: "myTargetFunction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)`

Comment: I am new to iOS/Swift, I wonder if using `myTextField.addTarget` is exactly equivalent to your delegate approach

Comment: yesh, sorry about that, Touch down does work it seems the docs are showing htat, I should have been more clear

Comment: Yes, this is how Apple works, the uitextfield is a UIControl delegate which intercepts touch events and stores them in an NSSet

Comment: the textfield delegate methods is the equivalent, sort of , of using (sender: blah) with uibutton intercepts, its the same principle

Comment: so, isn't it neater to use `addTarget()` instaed of adding the `UITextFieldDelegate` to the class?

Comment: I would say it's neater, but the delegate methods are already set up for easy use, they separate out the NSSet  of toucehes for you, per se, so it's easier for you to plan around it, but then again, this "EditingDidEndOnExit" is the same thing as calling the delegate method, but what does this doe for Apple? it's MVC programming, they have a subclass of NSObject which is the UITextfield that is a delegate of UiControl, so it's by design they have this set up this way, the class of UITextField should control it's own actions, not its delegate object, but either way its fine

Comment: Also, should you ever want to customize a UITextField and make your own subclass, you can the "control events" to customized what you want to ahve happen given your custom UITextField, this can get very very compplicated, but this is another reason, it's for some very advanced programming

Comment: Thanks for your explanations!

Answer (score 11):

> Update For Swift 3

Here is the code for Swift 3:

```
myTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myTargetFunction), for: .touchDown)
```

This is the function:

```
func myTargetFunction() {
    print("It works!")
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I referred to the [UIControlEvents documentation from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrolevents) and came up with the following:

First add UITextFieldDelegate to your class then,

```
textBox.delegate = self
textBox.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TextBoxOn(_:)),for: .editingDidBegin)
textBox.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TextBoxOff(_:)),for: .editingDidEnd)
```

with the following functions:

```
func TextBoxOff(_ textField: UITextField) {
     code
         }                
}

func TextBox(_ textField: UITextField) {
    code
         }
}
```

Comment: All answer except your answer was useless for me! Only it worked perfectly! Thanks :)

Comment: Awesome Answer, Perfectly Worked for me, Thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

For Swift 3.1:

1) Create a gesture recognizer:

```
let textViewRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
```

2) Add a handler to the recognizer:

```
textViewRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tappedTextView(_:)))
```

3) Add the recognizer to your text view:

```
textView.addGestureRecognizer(textViewRecognizer)
```

4) Add the handler to your class:

```
func tappedTextView(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("detected tap!")
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To make this a little clearer these things need to be in place. I used this to make it so if a user entered something in an app of my own's  credit `textField` anything in the debit `textField` is deleted.

1. ***UITextFieldDelegate*** needs to be declared in the View controller i.e ***class SecondViewController:***
2. The detector functions  ***func myDebitDetector  func myCreditDetector*** need to be in the ViewController class.
3. put ***debit.addTarget and credit.addtarget*** inside view will appear.
4. ***@IBOutlet weak var debit: UITextField!***   and   ***@IBOutlet weak var credit: UITextField!*** are textfields on the storyboard and connected to the viewController.

   ```
   class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

   @IBOutlet weak var credit: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var debit: UITextField!

       func myDebitDetector(textfield: UITextField ){
           print("using debit")
           credit.text = ""

       }

       func myCreditDetector(textfield: UITextField) {
           print("using cedit")
           debit.text = ""
       }

       override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {



           debit.addTarget(self, action: "myDebitDetector:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
           credit.addTarget(self, action: "myCreditDetector:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
       ....

       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Set the UITextField delegate to your view controller

Obj-C

```
textField.delegate = self;
```

Swift

```
textField.delegate = self
```

Implement the delegate method

Obj-c

```
-(void)textField:(UITextField*)textField didBeginEditing {
   // User touched textField
}
```

Swift

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) {    //delegate method

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3.0 Version:**

```
textFieldClientName.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("myTargetFunction:")), for: UIControlEvents.touchDown)
```

Comment: This doesn't work... I'm getting: Value of type 'UITextView' has no member 'addTarget'

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.2.

Try *.editingDidEnd* instead of *.touchDown* and *delegate*.

```
myTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myTargetFunction), for: .editingDidEnd)

@objc func myTargetFunction(textField: UITextField) {
    print("textfield pressed")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On xamarin.iOS i easy to use:

```
YourTextField.WeakDelegate = this;
```

[...]

```
[Export("textFieldDidBeginEditing:")]
public void TextViewChanged(UITextField textField)
{
    if (YourTextField.Equals(textField))
        IsYourTextFileFocused = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
** Swift 4.0 + **
Use custom action like this


YourTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myTargetFunction(_:)), for: .allEditingEvents)

@IBAction private func myTargetFunction(_ sender: Any) {
        if let textField = sender as? UITextField {
            // get textField here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't the correct control event listener be .allTouchEvents instead of .allEditingEvents?

Comment: It can be any event listener